# When should (shouldn't) we use indefinite article (a) with "statement"?

Tags: indefinite-article, headlinese

When should (shouldn't) we use *indefinite article (a)* with "statement"?

Which one is correct?

> Arsenal know they have to make **statement** of intent at Manchester City. [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2016/dec/17/arsenal-statement-of-intent-manchester-city-arsene-wenger)

> Georginio Wijnaldum wants Liverpool to make **a statement** of intent at Sunderland this afternoon. [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-4080528/Georginio-Wijnaldum-urges-Liverpool-turn-pressure-leaders-Chelsea.html)

Comment: Articles are often omitted in headlines. In a conventional (non-headline) text, "statement" will take the indefinite article ("a statement").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headlines in English follow a set of grammatical rules known as [Headlinese](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese)

The reason of the omision of article in Headlines is that they are written in a "compressed" telegraphic style used to save space.